# Client-Server Model between Smartphones via BLE?

Tags: client-server, model

I want to have a Client-Server-Model with Smartphones within a range of 50 meters inside an application. One of the Clients is supposed to be the "Host" and it's only job is to receive data from all Clients and do something with it (not important). Everyone should be able to see all the other Smartphones, that have the app started, in a list. In addition every Client should be able to see, which of the Clients in the list the "Host" is, in order to send data to him.

I want to have the application decentralised, so that it doesn't depend on a database or something else, just on the few people which are using it in a range of 50m. The benefit I gain by that is, that multiple groups at different locations can use the app.

I'm struggling with the technology on which i want to build this setup.

My thoughts about **Bluetooth Low Energy:**

- easy to find all the people in range
- not dependent on Wifi/Internet
- **Problem:** the Clients cant determine the Host
- **Problem:** there are alot of other bluetooth devices, which aren't smartphones and should be ignored

Is there a better technique I could use? WiFi's disadvantage is that everyone has to be in it.

Comment: You could consider using wifi direct as it shares similar pros with BLE while also being a lot faster and effective. You can communicate information such as who is the host during a connection phase or even as a code in the SSID. This allows many devices to connect to the host which acts as a wifi modem of sorts.